# Color palette in OpenOffice Writer

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

How to load another color palette (*.soc file) in [OpenOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) [Writer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org_Writer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time but I found the answer finally. I do not know if there is a more intuitive way of changing the colour palette than this one.

You have to add a shape from Drawing Toolbox. Then right-click on that shape and click "Area...". Switch to the "Colour" tab where you will find a tiny button that can be used to load a colour palette (see image: http://czuk.eu/external_images/oo_colour_palette.png). What is funny, this icon does not appear in any other form with colours.